# Cannot use suds from VS with IronPython

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio-2015, ironpython, suds

I'm developing a WPF IronPython application with VS 2015. I have to send a SOAP call and to read the answer so I'm trying to get suds to work. Since both pip and easy_install failed to install it, I downloaded the sources, unzipped them, and put them in the site-packages folder. It worked, now I can see them from VS.

When I try to use these modules however the program crashes, this is what I have done:

```
from suds import *
from suds.client import Client

class Utils(object):
    def doStuff(addr, mail):
        cl = Client(addr, verify=False)
        cl.service.authenticate(email)
        cl.service.otherFunctions(...)
```

I know that not every module works with IronPython, so my question is: have I made some error? Or is it suds that doesn't work with IronPython? If the second, do you know of alternatives?

Thank you.